# Checkbox doesn't save true value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and Vuejs 2.

If I click on my checkbox and make the value true it's supposed to save a 1 in the database and if I click my checkbox and make the value false it saves a 0.

The problem I'm having is that if I click my checkbox and make it true, it doesn't save the correct value, no changes is made to the database and I don't get any errors. If I click on my checkbox and make it false, it saves the 0 correctly.

I did notice that even when my value is supposed to be true, I do get a false when I `dd($category->has('active')`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or how to fix it.

My vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Active</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(category, index) in categoriesNew" >
          <td>
            <label>checkbox 1</label>                        
            <input name="active" type="checkbox" v-model="category.active" @click="checkboxToggle(category.id)">
          </td>

          <td>
            {{ category.title }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

    props: ['categories'],

    data(){
      return {
        categoriesNew: this.categories
      }
    },

    methods: {
      checkboxToggle(id){
        console.log(id);
        axios.put('/admin/category/active/'+id, {
          categories: this.categoriesNew
        }).then((response) => {
          //Create success flash message
        })
      },
    },

    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

my routes

```
Route::put('admin/products/updateAll', 'Admin\ProductsController@updateAll')->name('admin.products.updateAll');

Route::put('admin/category/active/{id}', 'Admin\CategoryController@makeActive')->name('admin.category.active');

Route::resource('admin/category', 'Admin\CategoryController');
Route::resource('admin/products', 'Admin\ProductsController');
```

my CategoryController@makeActive

```
public function makeActive(Request $request, $id)
{
  $category = Category::findOrFail($id);

  if($request->has('active'))
  { 
    $category->active = 1;
  }else{
    $category->active = 0;
  }

  $category->save();
}
```

I hope I made sense. If there is anything that isn't clear or if you need me to provide more info, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
          categories: this.categoriesNew
```

to

```
categories: category.active
```

and add a data prop at the top called category.active: ''

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because when I add `category.active: ''` to the `data(){...}` section it has an issue with the dot between category and active

Comment: @Nikki Get rid of the period syntax

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work. This is what I did.

vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Active</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(category, index) in categories" >
          <td>
            <label>checkbox 1</label>                        
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="category.active" @click="checkboxToggle(category)">
          </td>

          <td>
            {{ category.title }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

    props: ['attributes'],

    data(){
      return {
        categories: this.attributes,
      }
    },

    methods: {
      checkboxToggle (category) {
        axios.put(`/admin/category/${category.id}/active`, {
          active: !category.active
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
        })
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

my routes

```
Route::put('admin/category/{category}/active', 'Admin\CategoryController@makeActive')->name('admin.category.active');
```

and my CategoryController@makeActive

```
public function makeActive(Request $request, $id)
{

  $category = Category::findOrFail($id);

  if(request('active') === true)
  {
    $category->active = 1;
  }else{
    $category->active = 0;
  }

  $category->save();
}
```